# Ignore input fields on form submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, webforms

I would like to include only certain form fields when submitting a form with jQuery.  For instance, I would like to ignore all fields that have the `disabled` attribute... maybe something like this:

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
    if($('input').hasAttr('disabled') {
        //ignore this form field when submitting
    }
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not necessary, `disabled` inputs are excluded **already**.  The various jQuery methods, including *submit()* and *serialize()* honour the HTML 4 specification for disabled controls in web forms, which goes as follows:

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are `disabled` cannot be successful.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Comment: +1 - For those curious, jQuery [performs the same filter when it serializes](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L97).

Comment: I was just about to post that i think it will ignore it by default anyway.

Comment: But a disabled-attribute can be set to false with javascript. In this case they will be submitted too, maybe that's the behaviour ThePixelProdigy want's to change.

Comment: @DrMolle: It's possible, but that's not the impression his question gives, which is asking for a way to exclude disabled controls from submission.

Comment: But this doesn't address the fundamental question. A complete answer would address, as an aside, the issue of disabled controls, but would focus primarily on the question itself: how to include an arbitrary subset of form controls in a form submission?

Comment: @dat: I disagree.  This answer also tells you that, if you want to send only a subset of form controls, you must first disable all others.